# How to find the last time the database was used by a live magento site

Tags: database, version

So here's the deal.
I have 5 magento databases made a couple of months ago when I upgraded magento from 1.8.0 to 1.9.2.4

Now I need to archive these database (for backup purposes) according to their versions and last used since I made a couple of copies.
I totally forgot to label any of these databases as to what their magento versions are or when I managed to download them.

I can tell that one has to be the 1.9.2.4 version since it has no content yet but the other are 1.8 and I have no idea which was the original or which was the one I was going to upgrade to magento 1.9.2.4

What tables do I look at to check the last usage of the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try looking at the date/time orders were created? Assuming orders were coming in on the site when these different database copies were being used, that might give you some direction as to what database might've used when. You can start by looking in the catalog_product_entity table & there should be a field in there called created_at. I'm doing this off the top of my head, but hopefully that helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: that is actually a good suggestion.  Will update you if your solution works.  Time to dig into the database then.

Comment: yup works for me.  found the older database and made a backup of the new one.  now off to testing extensions.